# c++ sort vector of template <char*, char*> objects

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, template-specialization

I need to implement this code so that it works:

```
Pair<char*, char*> p1, p2, p3;
vector<Pair<char*, char*> > v;
cin >> p1 >> p2 >> p3;
v.push_back(p1);
v.push_back(p2);
v.push_back(p3);
sort(v.begin(), v.end());

for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

I made template class, tested all operators and everything works fine, but now I need to make specialization for my class so that upper code works. Here is what I did:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Pair
{
T1 first;
T2 second;

public:
    Pair(const T1& t1=0, const T2& t2=0) : first(t1), second(t2){}
    Pair(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) : first(other.first), second(other.second){}

    bool operator==(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) const{
        return first == other.first && second == other.second;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) const{
        return first != other.first && second != other.second;
    }

    bool operator<(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) const{
        return first < other.first && second < other.second;
    }

    bool operator<=(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) const{
        return first <= other.first && second <= other.second;
    }

    bool operator>(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) const{
        return first > other.first && second > other.second;
    }

    bool operator>=(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) const{
        return first >= other.first && second >= other.second;
    }

    Pair<T1, T2>& operator=(const Pair<T1, T2>& other){
        first=other.first;
        second=other.second;
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Pair<T1, T2>& b){
        os << "Values: " << b.first << " " << b.second << endl;
        return os ;
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Pair<T1, T2>& p){
        is >> p.first >> p.second;
        return is;
    }

    friend void swap(Pair<T1, T2>& a, Pair<T1, T2>& b){
        Pair<T1, T2> t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
};
```

I know that for specialization I need to write code separately, so I did this:

```
template<>
class Pair<char*, char*>{
char s1, s2;
public:
    Pair(const char t1='x', const char t2='y') : s1(t1), s2(t2){}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Pair<char*, char*>& b){
        os << "Values: " << b.s1 << " " << b.s2 << endl;
        return os ;
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Pair<char*, char*>& p){
        is >> p.s1 >> p.s2;
        return is;
    }

    friend void sort(){
        // ???
    }
};
```

Operators << and >> works fine, but I stuck on sort because I have no idea how to implement sort method so that it works and sorts alphabetically letters in this specialization for template object. Googled, but not much there, so any hints or help will be appreciated...

Comment: _`first == other.first`_ When these are `char*` pointers, the condition will unlikely be true. You probably need a specialization and use `strcmp()`.

Comment: Get rid of all pointers (you do it wrong) . Use std::;string or char (single characters), depending on your intention.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I totally forgot to implement operator== for char type but I don't think I will have problems there. I need help with sort() method

Comment: I can not change code in first section, because thats how my professor wants it to be. I know it would be simpler as you suggest, but unfortunately it must be this way.

Comment: In addition to using `strcmp` to compare the strings (and not the addresses stored in the pointers), all the comparisons except `operator==` are wrong. Two pairs can be different if only one of the members differ. And for the others, what if `first` is less and `second` is greater that the other pair?

Comment: why not to use comp? refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: Your `Pair<char*, char*>` look more than `Pair<char, char>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specialization is inconsistent with your general case.

The `template<T1, T2> class Pair;` contain a member of type `T1` and a member of type `T2`.

So, to be consistent, `template<char *, char *> class Pair;` should contain two `char *` (and allocate/deallocate it, I suppose). Instead, your specialization contain two `char`. Very naive.

What were your intentions? Crete a pair for `char *` (C-style strings) or a pair for single `char` characters?

As it is, and as observed by Bo Persson, you relational operators (in generic class) are really bad. Also wanting ignore that (IMHO) is better develop relational operators as `friend` and not as class methods, it's important that if result true `a == b`, `a != b` result false and conversely. Otherwise, the `std::sort()` can crash the program.

Look at `operator==()` and `operator!=()` implementations

```
bool operator==(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) const{
    return first == other.first && second == other.second;
}

bool operator!=(const Pair<T1, T2>& other) const{
    return first != other.first && second != other.second;
}
```

Consider the case `first == other.first` and `second != other.second`; the result is that both operator returns `false`. That is dangerous; really dangerous.

Same problem with other relational operator.

Consider the case `first < other.first` and `second > other.second`; all four other operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) return `false`.

I strongly suggest you to write the relational operator in a inter-dependent way; something like

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
   bool operator== (const Pair<T1, T2> & p1, const Pair<T1, T2> & p2)
    { return (p1.first == p2.first) && (p1.second == p2.second); }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
   bool operator!= (const Pair<T1, T2> & p1, const Pair<T1, T2> & p2)
    { return ! (p1 == p2); }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
   bool operator< (const Pair<T1, T2> & p1, const Pair<T1, T2> & p2)
    { return    (p1.first < p2.first) 
             || ((p1.first == p2.first) && (p1.second < p2.second)); }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
   bool operator<= (const Pair<T1, T2> & p1, const Pair<T1, T2> & p2)
    { return ! (p2 < p1); }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
   bool operator> (const Pair<T1, T2> & p1, const Pair<T1, T2> & p2)
    { return (p2 < p1); }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
   bool operator>= (const Pair<T1, T2> & p1, const Pair<T1, T2> & p2)
    { return ! (p1 < p2); }
```

remembering to declare `friend` in classes, `operator==()` and `operator<()`.

p.s.: caution, example code not tested.

p.s.2: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. I implemented operator< for specialization so it compares 2 letters:

```
bool operator<(const Pair<char*, char*>& other) const{
    return s1 < other.s1;
}
```

this way I can use sort method by default for my vector:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

I know there are cases where letters can be equal, but I can do it with couple more ifs, idea is more important. Thanks everyone for help!